# Why does changes made to a autowired field affect another autowired field in another class?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Considering the following sample code:

```
public class SmallCar {
    private CarEngine carEngine;

    @Autowired
    public SmallCar(CarEngine carEngine) {
        carEngine.setBrand("Brand A");
        this.carEngine = carEngine;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        carEngine.printBrand();
        carEngine.printStatus();
    }
}

public class Bus {
    private CarEngine carEngine;

    @Autowired
    public Bus(CarEngine carEngine) {
        carEngine.setBrand("Brand B");
        this.carEngine = carEngine;
    }

    public void printInfo() {
        //...
    }
)
```

I've found that `SmallCar.printInfo()` would print out "Brand B" if `Bus` is processed by spring after `SmallCar`. Does it mean Spring is returning the same bean for both class? How should I modify the code so that they both get their own copy?

I thought it was safe to assume a new instance is returned each time but apparently it is not? isn't that the more reasonable design considering the possible side effects?

Comment: "isn't that the more reasonable design considering the possible side effects?" .. not using singleton beans in the default "mode" would add _much_ more overhead when autowiring beans. Don't forget that Spring has much more beans in its environment then just your small `CarEngine`, it also has configured persistence beans, security contexts etc. Creating and configuring them each time isn't that desirable. Also I wonder why you want to autowire `CarEngine` in the first place. Why do they need to be a Spring bean?

Comment: @Tom Project structure thing. Everything needs to be a Spring bean as required by user

Comment: @Tom:  Who says you can't put a Ferrari engine into a bus?  :)  I'd imagine that this also exercises the separation of concerns of those components; the cars themselves don't really care what kind of engine they get as long as they get *an* engine.

Comment: @Makoto I wouldn't argue against IoC here, but debate about who should inject the dependency. It might be more useful to let the class creating a `Bus` or `SmallCar` instance(s) do that. Or at least make `CarEngine` immutable and use a qualifier like you suggested in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, every bean in Spring is a singleton. But, this can be changed.

You would have to declare `CarEngine` as either a [prototype bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)...

```
@Bean(scope = "prototype")
public CarEngine carEngine() {
   // car engine here
}
```

...or ideally, have two `CarEngine` beans which are different brands.

```
@Bean(name = "brandA")
public CarEngine carEngine1() { }

@Bean(name = "brandB")0
public CarEngine carEngine2() { }
```

Then you can use them with `@Qualifier`.

```
@Autowired
public SmallCar(@Qualifier("brandA") CarEngine carEngine) {
    this.carEngine = carEngine;
}

@Autowired
public Bus(@Qualifier("brandB") CarEngine carEngine) {
    this.carEngine = carEngine;
}
```

Comment: So this is by design? But what if someone else autowire the same component and changes some value? It may break old code and that would be very hard to debug... Anyway I would tried to add named bean and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I've registered 2 named beans inside my `CarEngine` and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @jack3694078 - supposing that you *could* change the state of a wired bean, it's pretty poor practice to do so, given that the very circumstance in which you describe would be any engineer's worst nightmare.